# UWP FileSavePicker Contract File Processing

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, filesavepicker

In my App i'm using a a FileSavePicker Contract (Provider). So other Apps could save files to my App. I implemented it, as it is shown on MSDN. The Problem now is, that i have to process a "saved" file, but how do i know, when the saving is completed? Here is my handler

```
private async void FileSavePickerUI_TargetFileRequested(FileSavePickerUI sender, TargetFileRequestedEventArgs args)
{
        var deferral = args.Request.GetDeferral();

        string saveFileName = sender.FileName;

        StorageFolder fileSavePickerContractTempFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.CreateFolderAsync("FileSavePickerContract", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        StorageFile fileSavePickerContractTempFile = await fileSavePickerContractTempFolder.CreateFileAsync(saveFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        args.Request.TargetFile = fileSavePickerContractTempFile;

        deferral.Complete();
    }
```

Target of my app is the anniversary update (1607). After deferral.Complete() i Need to to more work with that file for integrating in my App. Can someone Point me in the right direction?

Comment: use `await fileSavePickerContractTempFolder.CreateFileAsync().ContinueWith((s,a)=> { <!-- Write your code here --> })`

Comment: IAsyncOperation<StorageFile> does not contain a Definition for 'ContinueWith'

Comment: Try this and see if it works?  `StorageFile fileSavePickerContractTempFile = await fileSavePickerContractTempFolder.CreateFileAsync(saveFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting).AsTask<StorageFile>().ContinueWith((file) => { <!-- Your Code Goes here --> return file.Result; });`

Comment: Did also not work. On the "<!-- Your Code Goes here -->", i call a method and pass the StorageFile in, but the StorageFile has even 0bytes at this Point.

Comment: No more ideas to this Problem?

Comment: I have now implemented a CachedFileUpdater which triggers the "OnCacheFileUpdaterActivated" Event in App.xaml.cs. From there i can work with the complete file. But if i Launch my app after that and will Close it, a Dialog says: "You are using TestApp in another App for saving a file. If you Close TestApp, the file may not be saved". So i think i Need to Report the successful saving somehow, because the file is saved completely. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the CacheFileUpdater i can react to the file, as soon it is written completely

```
CachedFileUpdater.SetUpdateInformation(fileSavePickerContractTempFile, url, ReadActivationMode.NotNeeded, WriteActivationMode.AfterWrite, CachedFileOptions.None);
```

On App.xaml.cs i override now the "OnCachedFileUpdaterActivated" Event, in which i can perform some Actions with the completely written file. So this works now as expected.

BUT! This does not work on Windows 10 Mobile, there the OnCachedFileUpdaterActivated EventHandler on App.xaml.cs gets not fired, why is this?

Comment: Can nobody help me out with this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue. Don't know how to fix it. The DropBox app works somehow, but not mine. DropBox did the same thing (some time ago): http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2013/03/25/win8-the-cached-file-updater-contract-or-how-to-make-more-useful-the-file-save-picker-contract/

Answer (score 0):

Your file is saved after the line with `await CreateFileAsync`. Method `CreateFileAsync` by itself returns `IAsyncOperation`, if you `await` it, the next line after `await` will be executed when this operation completes.

Comment: Yes, but if i want to process a file, which is saved for example from the dropbox app, then this file is still downloading and the filesize is 0.

Comment: Its pick the file to save not to finished.

Comment: And how do i know when it is finished?